# Pandas assign values from 1st element nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have df:

| itemMaterial | pcs | thickness | sizeL(mm) | sizeW(mm) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| steel | 5 | 15 | 1200 | 1000 |
| aluminium | 7 | 19 | 800 | 600 |
| steel | 2 | 10 | 500 | 500 |
| wood | 1 |  | 900 | 700 |

`weightsPerM2 = [[aliuminium19, 14], [steel15, 20], [steel25, 35] [wood, 8], [steel10, 13]]`  - i choose to store in list, maybe better way?

Need to get something like this:

| itemMaterial | pcs | thickness | sizeL(mm) | sizeW(mm) | m2 | weights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| steel | 5 | 15 | 1200 | 1000 | 6 | 120 |
| aluminium | 7 | 19 | 800 | 600 | 3.36 | 67.2 |
| steel | 2 | 10 | 500 | 500 | 0.5 | .. |
| wood | 1 |  | 900 | 700 | 0.63 | .. |

Calculation of first row(steel15): `m2 = 1.2*1*5 = 6` (mm converted to m and multiplied by pcs)
weights of first row(steel15): `m2*weightPerM2 = 6 * 20 = 120` (m2 multiplied per steel15 weight from list)

```
for i in df.itertuples()
    if i.itemMaterial in weights:..
        list.append(i.itemMaterial)
```

1. How iterate and search over nested list 1st element with condition?
2. Add additional column 'Weights' to df which is `itemMaterial&thickness(weights[1])*pcs`
3. Maybe pandas has method to drop values from list and show matched values.

P.S. I forgot to mention, that happens that not all weights exist in list, so why I thought iterate and not existing materials/thicknesses add to additional list and get notification, check out things..

Comment: You should accept  correct provided answer. Please note that accepting the answer helps that your issues is resolved. None of your questions' answer are marked as resolved.

Comment: I havent forgot, I had not so time to test all things in depth. Im testing then maybe asking in comments, when I will finish with topic I will definitely mark and close.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your list of lists to dataframe and `merge`

```
data = {'itemName': ['door', 'hand'],
        'itemMaterial': ['steel', 'aluminium'],
        'pcs': [5, 7],
        'thickness': [15, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

weights = [['aluminium', 14], ['steel', 20], ['wood', 8]]
dfw = pd.DataFrame(weights, columns=['itemMaterial', 'weight'])

df = df.merge(dfw, on='itemMaterial', how='left')
df['weight'] *= df['pcs'] * df['thickness']
```

```
>>> df 

  itemName itemMaterial  pcs  thickness  weight
0     door        steel    5         15    1500
1     hand    aluminium    7         19    1862
```

Comment: Hey. Thx as always. My bad.. I thought that it will though iteration so I omit some nuances because I could done.. Wont do that anymore.. Actually I have additional column THICKNESS(int/float) in my df, so assignation must be through two columns: itemMaterial+thickness(steel19, aliuminium15) and list with weight [[aluminium15,  14], [steel19, 20 ]]

Comment: Can you store weight into another form because 'aluminium15' is hard to parse? And why wood has no thickness?

Comment: Thickness just attribute for material which changes weights in list(2nd element of nested list/ integer), because can be steel thickness 10 and 21 -> weights = [[steel10, 30], [steel21, 62 ]]. Materials with only one thickness not marked because weight is permanent, as wood without thickness. Also weights in list its weights per m2 of this thickness material, m2 I have calculated before.. Not sure do u u need that but just for sure. I see bad in my question and need to show final result which I wanna get. Ok I wil edit topic. Thx.

Comment: Buddy, maybe u have offer? :) I solved it through loops, but would be nice to see pandas way :).